# How to add users in redmine project

Tags: redmine

I created a project in Redmine and created users to add in this project.

Now how can they see our project in the redmine? How can they activate themselves? 
I know that e-mail should be sent to them or if they make an account for themselves: How can I invite them to our project? The path that I'm using to do so is: `Administrator -> Users -> new user`. But here, only users found that I created myself.

Can the Adminstrator accesses the users password?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

An administrator can change users passwords.

He can also define roles and groups and assign users to this roles and groups. He also can give permissions to users, roles and groups to acces projects and configure what they can do in the projects and whats not.

For you:
You should define a group or a role and give permissions to that to access your project. You can do this in the "groups" / "roles and permissions" administration panel-

After that you should assign a user to the created group/role by open the user profil (URL: `.../users/<ID>/edit`) and then switch to the tab `Groups`or `Project` and assign them there

On the users panel (`Administration -> Users`) there is also a filter to only show active / inactive / all users. Maybe you are hiding some other users.

edit:
You can change the account activation mode under `administration -> settings -> tab: "authentication"`. There's an combobox with something like "Signup" where you can choose

- closed
- Activation via e-Mail
- Manual activation
- Automatic activation

Under the `administration -> user` settings in the filter combobox you can filter for `non activated users`, open their profile and activate them manually.

Comment: ok. I done this works. but how can they understand? because no e-mail  been sent to them.

Comment: What do you mean by "how can they understand"? I also edited my post about a part where you can change the authentication method. But if no email was send then check your email-settings under `administration -> settings -> Email notifications`.